# "Валять дурака" — происхождение фразеологизма

Tags: фразеология

Когда человек бездельничает или занимается ерундой, говорят, что он валяет дурака. А откуда пошло это выражение и что оно значило изначально?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Большинство фразеологических словарей ведут выражение *валять дурака (Ваньку)* от игрушки Ванки-встаньки. Валять её занятие, действительно, бесполезное и стать синонимом безделья такое времяпровождение вполне могло. Однако, как мне кажется, заслуживает внимания ещё одна версия.

Дураком и Ванькой зачастую называли мужской половой орган. Соответственно, *валять дурака*, тогда означает - заниматься онанизмом. Словарь синонимов, в частности,  приводит данный фразеологизм в ряду к слову "мастурбировать". Рукоблудие довольно часто в русском языке, ассоциируется с бездельем, поэтому по-моему, эту версию со счетов сбрасывать, тоже не стоит.

Answer (score 3):

Я думал что термин связан с производством валенок, войлочными отходами, их катали от безделья, получался "дурак", просто бесполезное изделие в виде войлочного мотка.

Comment: Во всяком случае версия совсем не хуже "мастурбирующей".

Comment: С утра баклуши били, после обеда валенки катали, разумно!

Answer (score -1):

Пожалуй, вариант, где "валять" подразумевает "ласкать", ближе русскому народу. Тогда и поговорка "Не поваляешь, не поешь" звучит как "Не приласкаешь жену, не поешь".

Comment: А если к Вопросу вернуться?